# drupal 7 module .install unable to create table

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i have created module but unablet to create table below is my code of mysubscribers.install

**mysubscribers.install**

```
function mysubscribers_schema(){
    $schema['mysubscribers'] = array(
        'description' => 'The table for storing the subscriber data.',
        'fields' => array(
            'id' => array(
                'description' => 'The primary identifier for subscriber.',
                'type' => 'serial',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'unsigned' => TRUE,
            ),
        ),
        'primary key' => array('id'),
    );
    return $schema;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */

function mysubscribers_install() {
  if (db_table_exists('mysubscribers')) {
    db_drop_table('mysubscribers');      // old table from 5.x-2.x
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to uninstall and reinstall the module to get HOOK_schema to fire. No need to delete the table on uninstall.

Comment: @gaurav is it new module on your website or it already works?

Comment: Does database user have permissions to create tables?

Answer (score 0):

No issues here when running your code.
You don't need to remove the DB on install.
If you make changes to the schema add your changes to hook_update()
with something like db_change_field() or db_add_field().

As long as your naming convention is correct this should work.
assuming you have a mysubscribers.info,mysubscribers.module, and mysubscribers.install